# What does Addition distribute over?

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory

I was considering I’m trying to find (hopefully continuous) functions $f: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that obey

$$ K + f(x,y) = f(x+K, y+K) \forall K \in \mathbb{C} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $f(x,y)=x+f(0,y-x)$, thus the general solution will be $f(x,y)=x+g(y-x)$ where $g$ is an arbitrary function.

Comment: I got one, $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}( 1 + x + \frac{1}{2} x^2 ) + \frac{1}{2} ( 1 + y + \frac{1}{2}y^2 ) - \frac{1}{2} xy $ now trying to connect it to your form

Comment: @frogeyedpeas $x+1+(y-x)/2+(y-x)^2/4$.